# generate encoder signal without using delay

Tags: arduino, encoder, signal-generator

I'm looking to emulate an encoder signal using an Arduino microcontroller (Seeed Xiao, SAMD21 Cortex M0+).

The following works but locks up the main thread with delays. The frequency of pulses isn't critical, but around 100 kHz to 1 MHz is preferred.

```cpp
kPulseDelayMicroSeconds = 1;
pulses = 10000;
for (int i; i < pulses; i++)
{
    delayMicroseconds(kPulseDelayMicroSeconds);
    digitalWrite(kEncoderAPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(kPulseDelayMicroSeconds);
    digitalWrite(kEncoderBPin, HIGH);
    delayMicroseconds(kPulseDelayMicroSeconds);
    digitalWrite(kEncoderAPin, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(kPulseDelayMicroSeconds);
    digitalWrite(kEncoderBPin, LOW);
}
```

What's a good way of running this in its own "thread"?

This is what I came up with so far.

```cpp
static const int kEncoderForwardPulseSequence[4][2] =
    {{1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 0}};

static const int kEncoderReversePulseSequence[4][2] =
    {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};

uint8_t _encoder_sequence_index = 0;
int32_t _pulses_to_send = 1000;

void ISR()
{
    if (_pulses_to_send != 0)
    {
      if (_pulses_to_send < 0)
      {
        digitalWrite(kEncoderAPin,
                     kEncoderReversePulseSequence[_encoder_sequence_index][0]);
        digitalWrite(kEncoderBPin,
                     kEncoderReversePulseSequence[_encoder_sequence_index][1]);
      }
      else 
      {
        digitalWrite(kEncoderAPin,
                     kEncoderForwardPulseSequence[_encoder_sequence_index][0]);
        digitalWrite(kEncoderBPin,
                     kEncoderForwardPulseSequence[_encoder_sequence_index][1]);
      }
        _encoder_sequence_index = (_encoder_sequence_index + 1) % 4;
        if (_encoder_sequence_index == 0)
        {
            _pulses_to_send = _pulses_to_send - sgn(_pulses_to_send);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use a timer to create an ISR which fires at a regular interval. Inside that, update the outputs according to a table. You would iterate through that table to simulate encoder motion.

Comment: @Drew you should make your comment an answer imho

Comment: I just don't have the time to write it up in detail rn.

Comment: did you try analogWrite? it is PWM. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/analog-io/analogwrite/

Comment: Wasp, your TC and TCC appear to be pretty powerful peripherals. You probably could just set them up and let them just do the work for you. They will do it with precision. The TCC, in particular, can *generate a synchronized bit pattern across the waveform output pins* according to the documentation in section 31.1. You can also "bit bang" these, of course, and just use an interval timer. But given the speed and the desire for emulation, I'd just use the TCC and be done with it and move on with the rest of your coding.

Answer (score 0):

```
setup()
{
  digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(B, LOW);
}
  
void ISR()
{
  static count = 1;

  if(count == 1)
  {
    digitalWrite(A, LOW);
    count = 2;
  }
  else if (count == 2)
  {
    digitalWrite(B, HIGH);
    count = 3;
  }
  else if (count == 3)
  {
    digitalWrite(A, HIGH);
    count = 4;
  }
  else if (count == 4)
  {
    digitalWrite(B, LOW);
    count = 1;
  }
}
```